# XCode, objective C - Keyboard WILL NOT SHOW

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I've taken over the work on an iOS app, I've managed to work quite well with it thus far adding new functionality despite not being a trained iOS developer.  However I've hit a patch where I simply cannot get the keyboard to show on screen when I tap on a UITextfield, there are areas of the app where it works but any new areas I add this simply will not work.  Is there a standard bit of code that controls showing the keyboard when you tap a text field?

Need help

Comment: Keyboard is automatic - no code needed to "show" it. Does the insertion caret (`|`) start blinking in the text field? If not, then your text field may be covered by another view.. it may be outside the bounds of its superview... it may be disabled... etc. If it *does* show, then you need to look for code that is explicitly ***preventing*** the keyboard from showing.

Comment: When I tap the textfield it's like it doesn't even recognise that I've tapped on it...

Comment: OK, so it's not a matter of "how to show the keyboard" ... the problem is that something is preventing interaction with the text field. In my previous comment I listed the three most common reasons for this -- but without additional details, I can only suggest you look in those directions to debug it.

Answer (score 0):

Keyboard opens up automatically unless you forced to not open.

You can check following, See screenshots.

1. Enable is checked
2. User Interaction Enable is checked
3. If you are checking on simulator try “command + k” from keypad
4. textFieldShouldBeginEditing delegate returns TRUE

> ```
> -(BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField{
>     return TRUE;
> }
> ```

[image]

Comment: So it's now working ONLY on the simulator, on the device when I put breakpoints on it fires textFieldShouldBeginEditing when I tap the field, but textFieldDidBeginEditing never fires... on the actual iphone it still acts like it's not been tapped...

Answer (score -1):

Are you running on a simulator or a real device?

Comment: I've not got it working on simulator but not the device so need help with that...

Comment: Open the simulator and switch the  ```Simulator - > IO - > keyboard - > connection hardware keyboard options ```

Comment: No, it works on the simulator.  The keyboard won't show and the textfield doesn't seem to even recognise it's being touched when ran on the iphone

Comment: I guess there is another layer on the upper layer of your keyboard that covers the keyboard, causing the keyboard to become unresponsive